# Why -from Java- JSON returns this error? Clearly is in the JSON deserialization, but I cannot find exactly where it occurs

Tags: java, json, rest, vert.x

**Situation:**
[![from Postman, JSON returns the data correctly][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kk0J.png

**Server side:**
Enables the reading of the request body for all routes under /api/articulos.

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route("/api/articulos*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.get("/api/articulos/:cantcomp1/:cantcomp2/:tipoprod/:prodpadre").handler(bizArticulo::getOneReadingBarcode);
```

*Business*

```
private static final String SELECT_CBA = "select art.leyenda, $1 :: numeric as cantidad, uni.abreviatura, "
+ "round(((art.precio_costo * (art.utilidad_fraccionado/100)) + art.precio_costo) * ($2),2) as totpagar "
+ "FROM public.articulos art join public.unidades uni on uni.idunidad = art.idunidad "
+ "WHERE (substring(art.codigobarra,1,2) = ($3) and substring(art.codigobarra,3,6) = ($4))";
```

```
public void getOneReadingBarcode(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        Double cantComprada1 = Double.parseDouble(routingContext.request().getParam("cantcomp1"));
        Double cantComprada2 = Double.parseDouble(routingContext.request().getParam("cantcomp2"));
        String tipoProducto = routingContext.request().getParam("tipoprod");
        String productoPadre = routingContext.request().getParam("prodpadre");

        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();

        pgClient
        .preparedQuery(SELECT_CBA)
        .execute(Tuple.of(cantComprada1, cantComprada2, tipoProducto, productoPadre), ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {

                RowSet<Row> rows = ar.result(); // return always ONE ARTICLE

                List<Articulo> articulos = new ArrayList<>();
                rows.forEach(row -> {
                    articulos.add(fromBarCode(row));
                });

                response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .setStatusCode(200)
                .end(Json.encodePrettily(articulos));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .end(Json.encodePrettily(ar.cause().getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
```

```
private static Articulo fromBarCode(Row row) {
        String leyenda = row.getString("leyenda");
        BigDecimal cantComprada = row.getBigDecimal("cantidad");
        String abreviatura = row.getString("abreviatura");
        BigDecimal total_a_pagar = row.getBigDecimal("totpagar");

        Articulo articulo = new Articulo();

        articulo.setLeyenda(leyenda);
        articulo.setCant_comprada(cantComprada);
        articulo.setAbreviatura(abreviatura);
        articulo.setTot_a_pagar(total_a_pagar);
        return articulo;
    }
```

**Client-side**

```
private void validarArticulo() {
        switch (txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(0,2)) {

        case "20":
            Integer d = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(8, 12));
            Double decimal = d * 0.001; // convert to kilos

            System.out.println(
                    String.format("%.3f", decimal) + " | " +
                    String.format("%.3f", decimal) + " | " +
                    txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(0, 2)  + " | " +
                    txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(2, 8)
                    );
        
            PosAccess
            .getCodigoBarra(
                    decimal,
                    decimal,
                    txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(0, 2),
                    txtCodigoBarra.getText().substring(2, 8));
        case "77":

        }
```

```
public static ObservableList<Articulo> getCodigoBarra(Double cantComp1, Double cantComp2, String tipoProducto, String productoPadre) {
        ObservableList<Articulo> itemsArticulo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(Vertx.vertx());
        client
        .get(PORT, HOST, "/api/conceptos/" + cantComp1 + "/" + cantComp2 + "/" + tipoProducto + "/" + productoPadre)
//      .get(PORT, HOST, "/api/conceptos/")
//      .setQueryParam("cantcomp1", cantComp1)
//      .addQueryParam("cantcomp2", cantComp2)
//      .addQueryParam("tipoproducto", tipoProducto)
//      .addQueryParam("productopadre", productoPadre)
        .send(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
        
                response.bodyAsJsonArray().forEach(articulo -> {
                    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) articulo;
                    itemsArticulo.add(new Articulo(jo.getString("leyenda"), jo.getDouble("cant_comprada"), jo.getString("abreviatura"), jo.getDouble("tot_a_pagar")));                  
                });             
                
                System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());
                System.out.println(response.bodyAsJsonArray());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
        return itemsArticulo;
    }
```

**Ok, that's the code. When scan the barcode I get this error**

```
0,750 | 0,750 | 20 | 021162
oct. 11, 2020 6:33:18 A. M. io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at io.vertx.core.json.jackson.JacksonCodec.fromParser(JacksonCodec.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.json.jackson.JacksonCodec.fromBuffer(JacksonCodec.java:67)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.codec.impl.BodyCodecImpl.lambda$static$2(BodyCodecImpl.java:51)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpResponseImpl.bodyAsJsonArray(HttpResponseImpl.java:116)
    at consumer.PosAccess.lambda$0(PosAccess.java:45)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
... 22 more
```

Anyboy can help me?
TIA
Ernesto

Comment: The stack trace contains a call to `HttpResponseImpl.bodyAsJsonArray`. You should take a look the content of the response that you are receiving (i.e. this value: `HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();`)

Comment: Thank you @mcernak, but my verticle run on the server, and no have idea how debug this...

Comment: You could try `System.out.println(response.bodyAsString());` right after `HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();`

Comment: Well...the message is "<html><body><h1>Resource not found</h1></body></html>"...I think as @taygetos say. Malformed my "get" with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the wrong endpoint (i.e. `/api/conceptos/` instead of `/api/articulos`).


In the screenshot provided in the post, which illustrates a correct response, you are showing a response for url

```
192.168.0.15:8092/api/articulos/0.75/0.75/20/021162
```

but in the code you have

```
client.get(PORT, HOST, "/api/conceptos/" + cantComp1 + "/" + cantComp2 + "/" + tipoProducto + "/" + productoPadre)
```

Comment: Thank you @mcernak...spend hours for that error, I can't believe...shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiences, this error message:

```
io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character ('<'
```

usualy happens when you try to deserialize an api response into a json, but indeed the response is something like:

```
<html><body><h1>Resource not found</h1></body></html>
```

or

```
<html><body><h1>Internal server error</h1></body></html>
```

and the parsing fails at the first char `<`

For your case, this happens at `response.bodyAsJsonArray()` probably.

please make a debug output for the url what you are calling:

```
String url = "/api/conceptos/" + cantComp1 + "/" + cantComp2 + "/" + tipoProducto + "/" + productoPadre;
```

Comment: Thank you @taygetos...I think, probably, my error is in the "Get"...multiple parameters split with "/". It's ok that?

Comment: I can not debug your code, but to me it is suspicious that you formatted those doubles in your debug output string as `String.format("%.3f", decimal)` and you don't do the same for the get request.

Comment: But generally you should share your `/api/conceptos/` endpoint too

Comment: `String.format("%.3f", decimal)` it's only for debugging purposes...it's in `System.out...`

Comment: what i am saying is that whn you have a Double (which is 0.75 * 0.001) . When formatted -> `String.format("%.3f", a)` the output is 0.001. When not (which you are calling the api with) it is `7.5E-4` which is probably the incorrect format for your api.

Comment: Thank you @taygetos...you helped me think!